# A problem in showing Unicode Character when running Java artifact, but everything ok while running in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

The goal is to read from the database and write the records into a file.
When running code in IntelliJ IDEA, it writes Unicode characters as same as database content.
But when I build the artifact (Jar File) and run it in windows, the output file shows question mark character '?' instead of showing Database content correctly.
In another word, Although English characters and numbers are showing correctly, Problem occurs in non-English characters (e.g. Persian characters, Arabic or ...)

related parts of java code:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile.txt , true), "cp1256"));

while (resultSet.next()) {

    try {
    singleRow = resultSet.getString("CODE") + "|"
            + resultSet.getString("ACTIVITY") + "|"
            + resultSet.getString("TEL") + "|" 
            + resultSet.getString("ZIPCD") + "|"
            + resultSet.getString("ADDR");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.writeLog(Constants.LOG_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }

    out.write(singleRow + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Output file content by running IntelliJ IDEA DEBUG mode:

```
 130143|Active|ابتداي بلوار ميرداماد،کوچه سوم پلاک پنج|524|35254410 
 190730|Active|خیابان زیتون، بین انوشه و زیبا پلاک یک|771|92542001
```

Output file content by running corresponding JAR File:

```
130143|Active|35254410|524|??? ? ??? ??????? ????? ????
190730|Active|92542001|771|????? ??? ??????? ????? ??? ??
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with the program?

Comment: How are you examining the output file in Windows?  The Windows command window usually is restricted to a single windows-125x character set.

Comment: I open both output file(output by running IntelliJ IDEA and corresponding JAR File ) the same way, using notepad++ software

Comment: I see that the other fields show ASCII digits normally, but `resultSet.getString("TEL")` corrupts not only Arabic characters but ASCII digits as well.  This suggests that the problem is either the charset of your database connection, or the charset which was used to write the data.  What is your JDBC URL?

Comment: thank you VGR for your comments, but I checked and it was not the case. I think something is wrong with the character set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change your code as follows:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile.txt , true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
 
while (resultSet.next()) {

    try {
        singleRow = resultSet.getString("CODE") + "|"
                + resultSet.getString("ACTIVITY") + "|"
                + resultSet.getString("TEL") + "|" 
                + resultSet.getString("ZIPCD") + "|"
                + resultSet.getString("ADDR") ;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.writeLog(Constants.LOG_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }

    byte[] bytes = singleRow.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String utf8EncodedString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    out.write(utf8EncodedString + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

**String.getBytes()** uses the system *default character set*.You can see your **environment** charset via :

```
System.out.println("Charset.defaultCharset="+ Charset.defaultCharset());
```

When **running from IntelliJ** , the system default character set is taken from IntelliJ environment.

When **running from JAR** file, the system default character set is taken from the Operating system (Explained at the end).

Because of the different charset of your windows and IntelliJ environment, you get different output.

It is highly recommended to **explicitly** specify "ISO-8859-1" or "US-ASCII" or "UTF-8" or whatever character set you to want when converting bytes into Strings of vice-versa

```
singleRow.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659417/why-does-javas-string-getbytes-uses-iso-8859-1/12659567) for more ionformation

---

***what are Windows-1252 and Windows-1256 ?***

> **Windows-1252**
>
> Windows-1252 or CP-1252 (code page 1252) is a **single-byte**(0-255) character.
> encoding of the Latin alphabet, used by default in the legacy components of Microsoft Windows for English and many European languages including Spanish, French, and German.
> The first 128 code (0-127) is the same as the standard ASCII code. The other codes(128-255) depend on system language ( Spanish, French, German).
>
> **Windows-1256**
>
> Windows-1256 is a code page used to write Arabic (and possibly some other languages that use **Arabic** script, like **Persian** and Urdu) under Microsoft Windows.
> These are some **Windows-1252** Latin characters used for French since this European language has some historic relevance in former French colonies in North Africa. This allowed French and Arabic text to be intermixed when using **Windows 1256** without any need for code-page switching (however, upper-case letters with diacritics were not included).

***What should I Do when using Unicode(persian) characters?***

Because of existing some different characters that have similar notations such as “ی” and “ي”  in Persian, this encoding will replace “ی”  (U+06cc) with “ي”( U+064a), because ***Windows-1256***  has not  U+06cc character.

*for Persian, instate of using Windows-1256  use UTF-8 encoding to avoid encoding problems*.
*Consider that Windows-1256 uses only 1 byte and UTF-8 take more bytes (1 to 4 bytes.)*
A comparison of these encoding  are [here](https://bizbrains.com/blog/encoding-101-part-2-windows-1252-vs-utf-8/)

***How to change windows Default character set?***

now on  Microsoft windows  **Windows-1252** is the **default** encoding used by Windows systems in most western countries.

To change your Microsoft windows  default character set to suitable Unicode follow [this](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/changing-display-language-used-non-unicode-programs) .

If you change as follows to **Persian**, your default charset will be changed to **Windows-1256**

[image]

***How to change specific software character set (some for programming)?***

you must change your specific software Unicode as it’s instructions.

**1-    for notepad++**
[image]

**2-     on xml file or field**
[image]

**3-    For IntelliJ files**
Open the desired file for editing.
From the main menu, select File | File encoding or click the file encoding on the status bar.
Select the desired encoding from the popup.
[image]
If or is displayed next to the selected encoding, it means that this encoding might change the file contents. In this case, IntelliJ IDEA opens a dialog where you can decide what you want to do with the file: choose Reload to load the file in the editor from disk and apply encoding changes to the editor only, or choose Convert to overwrite the file with the encoding of your choice.

**4-IntelliJ  Console output encoding**
IntelliJ IDEA creates files using the IDE encoding defined in the File Encodings page of the Settings / Preferences dialog Ctrl+Alt+S. You can use either the system default or select from the list of available encodings. By default, this encoding affects console output. If you want the encoding for console output to be different from the global IDE settings, configure the corresponding JVM option:

1. On the Help menu, click Edit Custom VM Options.
2. Add the -Dconsole.encoding option and set the value to the necessary encoding. For example: **-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8**
3. Restart IntelliJ IDEA.